# ionic 2 ionViewDidEnter() can only run script once

Tags: javascript, typescript, twitter, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to call this function that runs a js script in my ts file.
The function is called using `ionViewDidEnter()`, but after the first time the script is no longer called.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log("Entered social media page");
    this.getTimeLine();
}

getTimeLine(){
    console.log("Getting twitter time line");
    !function(d, s, id){
        var js: any,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    } (document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
}
```

Comment: for what event do you need it to be called?

Comment: have you put  getTimeLine() inside your constructor?

Comment: Have you read the **Lifecycle Events** from Ionic's Documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)?

Comment: yes i have read the Life cycle Events, the console log in getTimeLine() prints out every time i enter the view, however the script does not run every time.

Comment: It only runs once because of that if check you have. Basically it says, if this has been added before then dont add it again therefore only running one time.